# Batch - Output all possible combinations of strings in two files

Tags: batch-file, combinations, permutation, batch-processing

I have **file A**:

```
AAAA  
BBBB 
CCCC 
....
```

and **file B**:

```
111
222
333 
...
```

I need a *batch code* to obtain a **file C** with all the combinations:

```
AAAA111
AAAA222
.......
CCCC333
```

Comment: Start with a blank text file.  Line 1 should be `@echo off`.  Line 2 should be `setlocal`.  That's a good place to start.  I suggest using a `for /F` loop to read file A and file B.  In a `cmd` console window, type `help for` and read for instructions.  **Spoiler:** Read #3 [on this page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php) to see how to nest two `for` loops.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Tested:

```
@echo off
set "file1=fileA.txt"
set "file2=fileB.txt"
set "file3=fileC.txt"

break>"%file3%"


for /f "useback tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%file1%") do (

  for /f "useback tokens=* delims=" %%$ in ("%file2%") do (
     echo %%#%%$>>"%file3%"
  )

)
```